# Calculating AVG between two tables (JOIN)

Tags: sql

The table PROBE looks like this:

`'ProbeID'-----   'TranscriptID' ---- 'Start'---- 'End'`

`'1056'-----------'7981326'----------'1013'---'1010'`

`'1057'-----------'7878826'----------'1011'---'1015'`

`etc..`

The table EXPRESSION2 looks like this:

`'ProbeID'-----   'SampleID' ---- 'Value'`

`'10425'---------'7981326'-----'16.55''`

`'11123'---------'7878826'----- '3.55'`

`etc..`

I need to find the top 100 largest differences in transcripts (i.e. take average of probes).

**Essentially, I need to link the ProbeID of the EXPRESSION2 table with the TranscriptID in the PROBE table and calculate the average for the top 100.**

I tried the code below, but keep getting "null" return. Any alternative scripts will be much appreciated. I think I am missing something.

**The EXPRESSION2 table has no null values, fyi**

`select avg(value)

from expression2

```
    where probeID in  
                    (   
                      select P.ProbeId 
                           from Probe P
                            join Transcript T on P.TranscriptID = T.TranscriptID
```

)`

limit 100;`

Comment: Do you have a NULL for any of the `Expression2 Value` records?  if you use `AVG(COALESCE(value, 0))` does that fix it?  If so, you may want to add a `WHERE` clause to limit your query not to return rows with 0 as the value of value.

Comment: I don't have any null values under the expression2 table. I have the where clause already included. Essentially, I need to link the ProbeID of the expression2 table with the TranscriptId in the Probe table and calculate the average for the top 100.

Comment: Does your problem become more clear if you change the AVG(value) to * briefly to see what data you're returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you whant to eliminate the null values

```
select e.probeID, avg(value) as avarage
from expression2 e
    inner join 
    (
        select P.ProbeId 
        from Probe P 
            join Transcript T on P.TranscriptID = T.TranscriptID    
    ) p on e.probeID = p.probeID
where e.value is not null
group by e.probeID
```

if you whant to treat them as 0

```
select e.probeID, avg(COALESCE(value,0)) as avarage
from expression2 e
    inner join 
    (
        select P.ProbeId 
        from Probe P 
            join Transcript T on P.TranscriptID = T.TranscriptID    
    ) p on e.probeID = p.probeID
group by e.probeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Which DBMS are you using? Is it significant that there are no matching ProbeIDs in the two tables in your example, but there are matching TranscriptID/SampleID pairs?

```
Select Top 100
  p.TranscriptID,
  Avg(e.Value)
From
  Probe p
    Inner Join
  Expression2 e
     on p.ProbeID = e.ProbeID
Group By
  p.TranscriptID
Order By
  2 Desc
```

Comment: Ignore the values above in the tables, it was just to provide the layout. The ProbeID will match. Thanks! I need to back track a bit, since I am still not getting any values back.